# Sharing method in Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, methods, share

When I share something with this method;

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=mypage.com" target="_blank">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Which texts does facebook retreive in my page to share? My titles in html code between `<title></title>`  or   headers between `<head></head>`     or      my body part between `<body></body>`?

I want to share only this text; "You calculated 3 + 2 and found it 5 "
How would you code this in HTML? (All page consists of only this text, there is nothing else)

It may be in PHP, XML or something else, doesn't matter. I just want to learn what facebook sees primarily in my page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook gets the title from the `<title></title>` tag and the description from the meta description tag
Like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="Description" />
```